# Karate - Replace a value with if condition

Tags: karate

I have the following json. I want to replace 'Türkiye' with 'Türkice' if a == "hello". Please help me with the guidance to add replace with the if condition combination

```
* def a = "hello"
    * def expected =
    """
    {
  "_": {
    "country-language-list": {
      "country-language": [
        {
          "_": "English",
          "@": {
            "languageCode": "en"
          }
        },
        {
          "_": "Deutsch",
          "@": {
            "languageCode": "de"
          }
        },
        {
          "_": "Türkiye",
          "@": {
            "languageCode": "tr"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "@": {
    "countryCode": "TR"
  }
}
    """
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
* if (a == 'hello') expected._['country-language-list']['country-language'][2]._ = 'Türkice'
```

Comment: Thanks much. This worked. Just one clarification here, are we adding the [ ] because the keys have special character '-' in it?

Comment: yeah, i was trying without these and it wasnt working. I tried changing the keys with names without the special char '-' and it was working. Thanks. learnt something new :)